# What's the difference between these two ways to make a 2D matrix?

Tags: javascript

`[...Array(9)].map(() => Array(10).fill(false))`

vs

`new Array(9).fill(new Array(10).fill(false))`

The first one where we use the `spread` syntax is the correct way to do it (I found this out after 2 hours of trying to do the Sudoku Solver problem). I have no idea though. What weird JavaScript is happening? When I would do `matrix[row][col]` with the second approach, it would make the entire column the value I assign it.

I'm just so confused.

Comment: When you use the second `.fill()` approach, you fill the array with multiple references to **the same single array**.

Comment: fill and map work in completely different ways. The best source for an answer is the docs for [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) & [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map)

Comment: @Pointy jesus that's so dumb. Even if I put `new` Array it still does that? That doesn't seem very new to me. Thank you

Comment: Yes, what happens is that the parameter you pass to `.fill()` is evaluated just once. Whatever that value is, an object, an array, the number 3, whatever, that's what's copied into each element of the array.

Comment: @Pointy thank you so much . saved me a lot of stress.